# MS Access UPDATE query fails as query is not updateble

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I want to use MS Access SQL to update a table `tblBillingPlan` that has as Primary key of ID.  I want to update the field `db_FeeType` with the value I have calculated in a group by query.

The FROM clause refers to qryGIT which returns two columns ID and FeeType.  Only one row returned for each ID.

```
UPDATE tblBillingPlan 
SET tblBillingPlan.db_FeeType = 
( SELECT MAX(GI.FeeType)
   FROM qryGIT AS GI
  WHERE GI.id=tblBillingPlan.ID
  GROUP BY GI.ID
);
```

When I run I get the error "query is not updatable".  How can I get around this?

I initially tried:

```
 UPDATE tblBillingPlan 
SET tblBillingPlan.db_FeeType = 
( SELECT GI.FeeType
   FROM qryGIT AS GI
  WHERE GI.id=tblBillingPlan.ID
);
```

Here is the definition of `qryGIT`

```
SELECT Billing_plan.id
     , Billing_plan.name
     , IIf(Max([Fee]) Is Null Or Max([Fee])=Min([Fee])
          ,Max([Fee])
          ,"BP has BP Fee rows with different fee types") AS FeeType

FROM Billing_plan 
     LEFT JOIN Billing_plan_fee 
            ON Billing_plan.id = Billing_plan_fee.billing_plan_id

GROUP BY Billing_plan.id, Billing_plan.name;
```

Note that `Billing_plan_fee`  will have up to four rows that match the given Billing_plan.id.

I also tried using the TOP modifier to only return one row which made no difference

```
UPDATE tblBillingPlanCPLAD 
SET tblBillingPlanCPLAD.FeeType = 

( SELECT TOP 1 GI.FeeType    -- TOP 1 made no differentce
   FROM GITAS GI
  WHERE GI.id=tblBillingPlan.ID
);
```

I'm about to do this using a DAO recordset, but I'm sure I used to write SQL that could do this in Oracle  and SQL server.  I'm rusty.

Comment: Are `Billing_plan` and `Billing_plan_fee` tables or views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access [Domain Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff836861.aspx#sectionSection6) functions can help when Access complains an `UPDATE` is not updatable.  In this case, use `DMax`:

```sql
UPDATE tblBillingPlan AS bp
SET bp.db_FeeType = 
    DMax(
        'FeeType',
        'qryGIT',
        'id=' & bp.ID
    );
```

However, `DMax` is Access-specific, so won't work in Oracle or SQL Server.

Comment: Oooo Thanks.  I'll let you know if it works.  I starting to think I should be using sql server as T-SQL gives so much more features.  Hmmm.